# Screenshot low quality iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, screenshot, reduce

In my project I have to make a screenshot of the screen and apply blur to create the effect of frosted glass. Content can be moved under the glass and then method bluredImageWithRect: called. I'm trying to optimize the following method to speed up the application. Major losses occur when a blur filter is applied to the screenshot, so I'm looking for a way to take a screenshot in a lower resolution, apply a blur to the screenshot, and then stretch it to fit some rect.

```
- (CIImage *)bluredImageWithRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGSize smallSize = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, smallSize.width, smallSize.height, 8, 0, colorSpaceRef, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationNone);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(ctx, NO);
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(ctx, NO);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);

    CGImageRef maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"].CGImage;
    CGContextClipToMask(ctx, rect, maskImage);


    [self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    CGImageRef imageRef1 = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);

    CGContextRelease(ctx);

    NSDictionary *options = @{(id)kCIImageColorSpace : (id)kCFNull};
    CIImage *beforeFilterImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef1 options:options];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef1);

    CIFilter *blurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, beforeFilterImage,  @"inputRadius", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0f], nil];
    CIImage *afterFilterImage = blurFilter.outputImage;

    CIImage *croppedImage = [afterFilterImage imageByCroppingToRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, smallSize.width, smallSize.height)];

    return croppedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tutorial [iOS image processing with the accelerate framework](http://invasivecode.tumblr.com/page/2) that shows how to do a blur effect that may be fast enough for what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works much faster than CIFilter solution. It now remains to make the picture color with alpha, I tried to change the colorspace to CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB and CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo to kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst, but now i have an error:  <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: invalid data bytes/row: should be at least 1280 for 8 integer bits/component, 3 components. Can you help me select the correct settings when you create a context?

Comment: I'm giving it a try, not much luck yet. To create the CGContextRef you need to use kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst.

Comment: Finally done this using example from here: http://indieambitions.com/idevblogaday/perform-blur-vimage-accelerate-framework-tutorial/

Comment: For future generations: the permanent URL for the post EarlyRiser refers to is http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/17202028681/ios-image-processing-with-the-accelerate